# htaccess - remove directory names from URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, directory

I Have the following site structure:

```
- index.php
- css/
- js/
- img/
- content/
  - product/
    - product-page-1.php
    - product-page-2.php 
  - static/
    - faqs.php
  - landing/
    - homeware-gifts.php 
    - stationary/
      - desks.php
```

So at the moment some of my URL's are like so but I need to hide the `content` and `product, static, landing` directories

**Products**:

```
mysite.com/content/product/product-page-2.php
```

to

```
mysite.com/product-page-2
```

**Static**:

```
mysite.com/content/static/faqs.php
```

to

```
mysite.com/faqs
```

**Landing**:

```
mysite.com/content/landing/homeware-gifts.php
mysite.com/content/landing/stationary/desks.php
```

to

```
mysite.com/homeware-gifts
mysite.com/stationary/desks
```

Note I am also wanting to hide the .php extension and I am currently using this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Which works but need to make sure that stays as well

Comment: So if URL is `mysite.com/aboutus` then `aboutus.php` can be in `product/`, `static/`, `landing/` or not found. This can be done but will be bit inefficient as it needs to check presence of `php` file in 3 directories.

Comment: If easier I can move all php page files into the `content` directory? So ignoring the product/static/landing directories

Comment: yes that will be excellent, I will post an answer with that assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /content/file.php to /file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+site1/content/(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /site1/%1 [R=301,NE,L]

## To internally rewrite /file to /content/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site1/content/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^site1/(.+?)/?$ site1/content/$1.php [L,NC]
```

This assumes there is no `.htaccess` inside `site1/` or anywhere else.

Comment: I have tried this but when I go to `mysite.com/content/product-page-1` I get the response `Not Found, The requested URL mysite.com/product-page-1 was not found on this server. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Why `/content/` in URL. You should be opening `mysite.com/product-page-1` URL and `product-page-1.php` should be placed inside `content/` directory.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Also I think I may have realised the mistake. I am working off another subdirectory, not the root. Are you able to adapt your answer to work for : `mysite.com/site1/content/product-page-1` can be accessed by `mysite.com/site1/product-page-1`? Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I will put the .htaccess in the root directory i.e `mysite.com`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your web server is Apache2, you have to put this in your vhost config :

```
    <Directory "/path/to/webroot">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride all
         Order allow,deny
         allow from all
    </Directory>
```

And then you will be able to play with .htaccess, first you will have to add

```
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
```

in all .htaccess and use this template :

```
    RewriteRule ^MySuperRewritePath$  /my/path/without/rewrite.php [L]
```

(As far as I know, you don't need to put a `.php` in rewrited URLs, so that's good for what you want)

Check out [official docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) if you want more infos